Includegraphics not aligning in amsart
I am trying to get the picture to algin within my Latex document within the AMS format:

\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}

This is where my picture is supposed to be:
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-plot,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pictex}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links

\newtheorem{theorem}{{\bf Theorem}}[section]
\newtheorem*{maintheorem}{{\bf Main Theorem}}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{{\bf Proposition}}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{{\bf Proposition}}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{{\bf Definition}}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{{\bf Lemma}}
\newtheorem{lemma*}{{\bf Lemma}}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{{\bf Notation}}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{{\bf Convention}}
\newtheorem{terminology}[theorem]{{\bf Terminology}}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{{\bf Example}}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{{\bf Corollary}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{{\bf Remark}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    % #############################################
    %
    %           Title, Authors, etc
    %
    % #############################################
    
    \title[ titles]%
    { Homology Structures }
    %\subjclass{%
        %   Primary 52C15; Secondary 30F99, 57M50}

    
    
    \author[X]{X} %

    
    
    \date{March 03, 2024}
    
    %\thanks{}
    
    
    
    \begin{abstract}
        We study 
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    \vskip 48pt
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{definition}
        This is a definition.
    \end{definition}
    
    

    
    
    
    %   <Canonical Examples>
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{IMG_2.jpg}}
            \caption{Caption here}
            %       \label{fig:figure_label}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
        
    
    
\end{document}

However no matter how I have tried, the scale is still too large and off centre. I have repeated adjusted the scale, width etc but to no avail. Much of the fixes on stack don't seem to address my issue. I had even reduced my file size but it does not seem to work. Is there a fix for this?
For reference my previewer looks like this:

Edit: Added fbox. Also the image runs as usual in document class article. It is only when it runs into this document class which results in these issues.

Welcome! Why do you put an image in display math mode?

I have clarified this

How? Would be interesting as an answer.

What does \begin{figure} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{IMG_2} \caption{Caption for the figure.} \end{figure} produce?

The image is loaded onto the previewer, but only a small part can be seen and it is overblown

I have attached the image as seen

The screenshot you display contains two elements -- the number "2" in the bottom left and the letter "x" at bottom center -- that aren't present in the code that purportedly generates the screenshot. Please clarify what's going on.

The 2 is the page number and the "X" is a segment part of my name. Those are separate parts of the code and is not really relevant here

well it looks as if your original picture is too large. Put a \fbox{} around it to see its dimensions.

Hmm.. the fbox bound seem to be where it should be, though not the image

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\includegraphics{example-image.jpg}}
\end{document}


You are explicitly specifying dvips processing of images
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

It is usually recommended not to specify this, and let the system choose the best option, however in this case your other settings make latex+dvips the only option, as:
You have pstricks:
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-plot,pst-grad}

so can not use pdflatex, and have 8 bit font setup:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

so can not use lualatex or xelatex.
LaTex/dvips can not include jpg files so you should have the error
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in example-image.jpg (no Boundi
ngBox).

If you supply a bounding box, for example in a .bb file or as
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 100 100]{example-image.jpg}

then latex will not error but the jpg file will be inlined into the resulting PostScript as if it were an EPS file and generate errors in your PostScript renderer.
Thus the output should not show the image at all.
